# Can I write my PhD thesis based on another student's paper if I'm a co-author?

Tags: phd, thesis, journals, science

My supervisor asked me to write my thesis based upon one paper which I'm co-author on. I was told to take results which were not published and extend the figures. I was also told to include some figures from the paper after I ask the journal for copyright permission, extend the discussion in the paper and insert all of this into my thesis. After all of this, I need to do one more experiment.

Is this usual in science and for a Ph.D.? What precautions should I take in this case?

Comment: I've attempted to clean up the question some. Please check to make sure it still follows what you originally asked.

Comment: I suppose this is not the only published paper that you will include in your thesis. You have also other papers for which you are the main author, right? The other person is also a PhD student? Should not the paper be included in his thesis?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is ok to include in your thesis a paper on which you are co-author (the answer is yes), or whether it is sufficient to have *only* this paper (the answer is probably no)?

Comment: Just to be sure, your thesis will not be based on one paper, right? Thesis usually have a lot more content than one or 2 papers....

Comment: @FábioDias I would say that depends on the field.  (And, sadly, some these have less than 1 paper in them.)

Comment: @Kimball: That is certainly true, but it is true in part because "one paper's worth of material" varies so much from field to field.

Comment: @Kimball Really? I mean, even a 30-page article, which is pretty big for my CS standards, should have less content than the average 100 page thesis. (I'm not challenging the affirmation, I just want more information, this is pretty weird considering the fields I'm used to)

Comment: @FábioDias I would say in most areas of pure math, a good thesis should give 1-2 papers.  Theses are generally written with a lot more introduction and background (and may also contain minor things not worth stand-alone publications).  Also, the formatting is very different expanding theses page counts.  My thesis (which I think was decent, not spectacular, and I believe around 80-90 pages) resulted in 2 short publications totalling < 15-20 journal pages.  Of course there was more background and related material in the thesis than the papers.

Comment: @ Alexandros I don't have a paper which Im the first author in.This Ph.D. student which I'm a coauthor of his paper will not write a thesis as a book but a list of his publication.Also, this procedure requested by my supervisor and I think he knows that such situation in write thesis is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

"Can I write my PhD thesis based on another student's paper if I'm a co-author?"

I feel a difference between the question title and the question content. It boils down, to me, to "were you a notably active contributor to this paper"?

*If the answer is yes*, and you take care about rephrasing published text, re-drawing figures, you can reuse the results. A thesis should be personal, and show your personal contributions. A PhD thesis based on only one paper is not uncommon in mathematics, yielding short theses. In other domains, you can expect to write one or two chapters for a published paper, by extending results, adding experiments. Not a whole thesis.

If the other student's contribution is significant enough, he should be acknowledged in the chapter introduction for instance: "this chapter is based on a joint work..."

*If the answer is no*, I am afraid it could be a case of plagiarism, and loose ethical behavior.

Comment: I'm active contributor to this paper, and this was of writing my thesis was  requested  by acceptance and advice of my supervisor and the main author of the paper!!